# Keeping wcf service configuration in separate file RRS feed

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I have a requirement to keep my Bindings,Services,Behaviours in separate or one common file and load it into the app.config.I tried many ways it didnt work.Finally i found one post about this.But thios one also not working for me.Can anyone help me to solve this.

It showing an error Unable to open configuration file
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

```
<configuration>
 
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services configSource="Services.config" >
    </services>
 
    <bindings configSource="Bindings.config">
    </bindings>
 
    <behaviors configSource="Behaviors.config">
    </behaviors>
 
  </system.serviceModel>
 
</configuration>
And then you can put your configuration settings in separate files like the following:

Behaviors.config

<configuration>
 
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services configSource="Services.config" >
    </services>
 
    <bindings configSource="Bindings.config">
    </bindings>
 
    <behaviors configSource="Behaviors.config">
    </behaviors>
 
  </system.serviceModel>
 
</configuration>


I got this from below post

 http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2011/01/06/Split-Config-files-in-several-files.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/q`enter code here`uestions/858225/configsource-doesnt-work-in-system-servicemodel-or-its-subsections/858320

please help me to solve this?
```

Comment: Check that the Services.config etc files are being copied to the WorkingFolder so the exe can pick them up. You might need to set those files to have `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy if newer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the properties of the configuration file:

[image]

Set the value of "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always".Both service.config and behavior.config files need to be set.

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services configSource="Services.config" >
        </services>
        <behaviors configSource="Behaviors.config">
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```